# What non-default Shapepar shapes are freely available?

Tags: examples, big-list, shapepar

The `shapepar`package comes with only a few templates for paragraph shapes.  Looking around the internet, I was unable to find many additional  `shapepar` creations.  As creating shapes in the package can be quite time intensive, I wanted to know what other shapes for the package had been created by the community, and which could be freely used by other TeX users.

Comment: Here is a start: [`shapepar is:answer`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=shapepar+is%3Aanswer)

Comment: I guess you want a list of answers linking to other answers which include suitable code, so I've added `big-list` and flagged for moderator attention. (I think only mods can make questions CW, though I'm not certain.)

Comment: Are you also interested in graphical interfaces where you can [design a shape in a GUI and convert it to `\shapepar`](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/software/flowframtk/manual/shapepar.shtml)?